# What is the probability of drawing the third white ball before the second black ball from a bag with $60$ white and $30$ black balls?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Balls are drawn repeatedly and with replacement from a bag containing $60$ white and $30$ black balls. What is the probability of drawing the third white ball before the second black ball?

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: In order for this to happen, you must already have drawn two white balls and either 0 or 1 black ball.

Answer (score 2):

The only possible scenarios that allow one to draw the third white ball before the second black ball are

⚪⚪⚪

⚫⚪⚪⚪

⚪⚫⚪⚪

⚪⚪⚫⚪

Compute the probability for each of these and add them to get your answer.